# how can I config virtio-net-pci to emulate a big endian linux for qemu-system-aarch64 running at a little endian

Tags: qemu, endianness, dpdk, pci, virtio

I emulate big endian linux by qemu-system-aarch64 with '-device virtio-net-pci' running at a little endian, and get the following error when i run dpdk l3fwd example.

```
#./examples/dpdk-l3fwd --log-level=pmd,8 -l 0 -- -p 0xf -L --config="(0,0,0)" --parse-ptype
EAL: Detected CPU lcores: 8
EAL: Detected NUMA nodes: 1
EAL: Detected static linkage of DPDK
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'
EAL: Probe PCI driver: net_virtio (1af4:1000) device: 0000:00:02.0 (socket 0)
[  150.096996] igb_uio 0000:00:02.0: uio device registered with irq 44
virtio_read_caps(): [98] skipping non VNDR cap id: 11
virtio_read_caps(): [84] cfg type: 5, bar: 0, offset: 0000, len: 0
virtio_read_caps(): [70] cfg type: 2, bar: 4, offset: 300000, len: 1048576
get_cfg_addr(): invalid cap: overflows bar space: 4194304 > 16384
virtio_read_caps(): [60] cfg type: 4, bar: 4, offset: 200000, len: 1048576
get_cfg_addr(): invalid cap: overflows bar space: 3145728 > 16384
virtio_read_caps(): [50] cfg type: 3, bar: 4, offset: 100000, len: 1048576
get_cfg_addr(): invalid cap: overflows bar space: 2097152 > 16384
virtio_read_caps(): [40] cfg type: 1, bar: 4, offset: 0000, len: 1048576
get_cfg_addr(): invalid cap: overflows bar space: 1048576 > 16384
virtio_read_caps(): no modern virtio pci device found.
vtpci_init(): trying with legacy virtio pci.
EAL: Cannot mmap IO port resource: No such device
eth_virtio_pci_init(): Failed to init PCI device
EAL: Requested device 0000:00:02.0 cannot be used
EAL: Probe PCI driver: net_virtio (1af4:1000) device: 0000:00:03.0 (socket 0)
virtio_read_caps(): failed to map pci device!
vtpci_init(): trying with legacy virtio pci.
vtpci_init(): skip kernel managed virtio device.
eth_virtio_pci_init(): Failed to init PCI device
EAL: Requested device 0000:00:03.0 cannot be used
TELEMETRY: No legacy callbacks, legacy socket not created
soft parse-ptype is enabled
L3FWD: Missing 1 or more rule files, using default instead
port 0 is not present on the board
EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1
  Cause: check_port_config failed
```

I find that it read config with following code in function virtio_read_caps

```
        ret = rte_pci_read_config(pci_dev, &cap, sizeof(cap), pos);
        if (ret != sizeof(cap)) {
            PMD_INIT_LOG(DEBUG,
                     "failed to read pci cap at pos: %x ret %d",
                     pos, ret);
            break;
        }
```

with definition of virtio_pci_cap as follows,

```
struct virtio_pci_cap {
    uint8_t cap_vndr;       /* Generic PCI field: PCI_CAP_ID_VNDR */
    uint8_t cap_next;       /* Generic PCI field: next ptr. */
    uint8_t cap_len;        /* Generic PCI field: capability length */
    uint8_t cfg_type;       /* Identifies the structure. */
    uint8_t bar;            /* Where to find it. */
    uint8_t padding[3];     /* Pad to full dword. */
    uint32_t offset;        /* Offset within bar. */
    uint32_t length;        /* Length of the structure, in bytes. */
};
```

so the `offset` and `length` is big-endian. but in [virtio-v1.1-cs01](https://docs.oasis-open.org/virtio/virtio/v1.1/cs01/virtio-v1.1-cs01.html) section 2.4, i get

```
Note: The device configuration space uses the little-endian format for multi-byte fields.
```

I guess that causes the problem, but there's no further information when i google it. It confuses me. Is it true that dpdk net/virtio driver does't support big-endian?

Comment: you already have information `eth_virtio_pci_init(): Failed to init PCI device`. please rerun with `--log-level=pmd,8` and edit the stackoverflow.

Comment: i have updated this question with new logs of `--log-level=pmd,8`, corresponding to dpdk-22.03, and the same problem exists in version dpdk-stable-20.11.2.

Comment: thanks for the sharing the new logs, as updated in the logs `rte_pci_ioport_map` fails. Cross checking the code base with dpdk 21.11.0 LTS looks like `rte_pci_ioport_map` is returning -1 which forces eth_virtio_pci_init failure. With respect to your question `does dpdk net/virtio driver support big-endian` I believe that is not the case. Since you are emulating `little endian` on `big endian` platform virtio-config area is becoming mangled hence configuration fails.

Comment: @sunbroy maybe the real question you are asking would be `how can I emulate virtio-pci config in little endian on a big endian platform for guest OS running as little endian`. Is this right understanding?

Comment: i emulate big endian linux on a little endian platform

Comment: as the question details ` big-endian linux emualted by qemu-system-aarch64`. Can you please update your question with the new information shared `i emulate big endian linux on a little endian platform`. Thanks for this information, then is your real question `how can I emulate virtio-pci config in little endian on a big endian platform for guest OS running as little endian`?

Comment: for `i emulate big endian linux on a little endian platform`, i mean the os run qemu-system-aarch64 is a little endian, and emulated by qemu is a big endian linux

Comment: @sunboary, thank you for updating the question for clarity as `how can I config virtio-net-pci to emulate a big endian linux for qemu-system-aarch64 running at a little endian`.

Answer (score 0):

there is option listed in QEMU for changing the endianness. Please [refer](https://qemu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interop/vhost-user.html)

```
VHOST_USER_SET_VRING_ENDIAN
id: 23
equivalent ioctl:
    VHOST_SET_VRING_ENDIAN
master payload: vring state description
Set the endianness of a VQ for legacy devices. Little-endian is indicated with state.num set to 0 and big-endian is indicated with state.num set to 1. Other values are invalid.

This request should be sent only when VHOST_USER_PROTOCOL_F_CROSS_ENDIAN has been negotiated. Backends that negotiated this feature should handle both endiannesses and expect this message once (per VQ) during device configuration (ie. before the master starts the VQ).
```

Note: I am not aware of the setting to be passed in KVM-QEMU (libxml) achieve the same.